# CSS horizontal scrollbars apear in chrome after resizing browser screen

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I'm currently developing an responsive website.

I have a very strange problem in Google chrome and on the default android internet browser.

It appears after the website is resized (Making the browser horizontally bigger  or change portrait to landscape view on android (over 480 pixels)).

When I resize the browser back to less then 480 pixels a horizontal scrollbar appears.

See for yourself at (loco para saxo .com / new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your css. for `navigation` You write  `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display:none` .

```
.moduletable_shop h3, #navigatie-horizontaal, .logo {
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
display: none;
}
```

Reason to write `display:none;` because `visibility: hidden;` hide the element but not remove the element but `display:none` remove the element.

Comment: Briliant!  Brilliant platform to thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Dirty way, but it works.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: good job, great find. Would be awesome to figure why it happens

Comment: Yeah, it will fix the scroll problem. Although as I said - it's dirty way. For now, I can see what is causing this problem. (I've tried on desktop Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

As sandeep has written, it happens because you use `visibility: hidden`. If you want to hide stuff, you should use `display:none` instead. According to w3schools-docs, `visibility: hidden` is:

*The element is invisible (but still takes up space)*